# Classify / Group mails by conversation thread in outlook using win32com?

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, pywin32, win32com

Is there a way to loop through all the mails by there `ConversationID`, `EntryID`
, `GetConversation`, `ConversationIndex` and group them based on same id number , so that they can be printed out as same as outlooks `find related` functions.

As 
`outlook.GetItemFromID(id)` only works on `EntryID` which is unique to all the mails.

i tried to loop through all the mails and find there respective id numbers and match if there is any mail having the same id number .
But all the id's seems to be unique .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [GetConversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getconversation) method of the `MailItem` class which obtains a [Conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.conversation) object that represents the conversation to which this item belongs.

GetConversation returns `Null` (`Nothing` in Visual Basic) if no conversation exists for the item. No conversation exists for an item in the following scenarios:

- The item has not been saved. An item can be saved programmatically, by user action, or by auto-save.
- For an item that can be sent (for example, a mail item, appointment item, or contact item), the item has not been sent.
- Conversations have been disabled through the Windows registry.
- The store does not support `Conversation` view (for example, Outlook is running in classic online mode against a version of Microsoft Exchange earlier than Microsoft Exchange Server 2010). Use the [IsConversationEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.isconversationenabled) property of the `Store` object to determine whether the store supports Conversation view.

The following sample code in C# (sorry, I am not familiar with python, but the Outlook object model is common for all programming languages) assumes that the selected item in the explorer window is a mail item. The code example gets the conversation that the selected mail item is associated with, and enumerates each item in that conversation, displaying the subject of the item.

```
void DemoConversation() 
{ 
 object selectedItem = 
 Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1]; 
 // This example uses only 
 // MailItem. Other item types such as 
 // MeetingItem and PostItem can participate 
 // in the conversation. 
 if (selectedItem is Outlook.MailItem) 
 { 
 // Cast selectedItem to MailItem. 
 Outlook.MailItem mailItem = 
 selectedItem as Outlook.MailItem; 
 // Determine the store of the mail item. 
 Outlook.Folder folder = mailItem.Parent 
 as Outlook.Folder; 
 Outlook.Store store = folder.Store; 
 if (store.IsConversationEnabled == true) 
 { 
 // Obtain a Conversation object. 
 Outlook.Conversation conv = 
 mailItem.GetConversation(); 
 // Check for null Conversation. 
 if (conv != null) 
 { 
 // Obtain Table that contains rows 
 // for each item in the conversation. 
 Outlook.Table table = conv.GetTable(); 
 Debug.WriteLine("Conversation Items Count: " + 
 table.GetRowCount().ToString()); 
 Debug.WriteLine("Conversation Items from Table:"); 
 while (!table.EndOfTable) 
 { 
 Outlook.Row nextRow = table.GetNextRow(); 
 Debug.WriteLine(nextRow["Subject"] 
 + " Modified: " 
 + nextRow["LastModificationTime"]); 
 } 
 Debug.WriteLine("Conversation Items from Root:"); 
 // Obtain root items and enumerate the conversation. 
 Outlook.SimpleItems simpleItems 
 = conv.GetRootItems(); 
 foreach (object item in simpleItems) 
 { 
 // In this example, enumerate only MailItem type. 
 // Other types such as PostItem or MeetingItem 
 // can appear in the conversation. 
 if (item is Outlook.MailItem) 
 { 
 Outlook.MailItem mail = item 
 as Outlook.MailItem; 
 Outlook.Folder inFolder = 
 mail.Parent as Outlook.Folder; 
 string msg = mail.Subject 
 + " in folder " + inFolder.Name; 
 Debug.WriteLine(msg); 
 } 
 // Call EnumerateConversation 
 // to access child nodes of root items. 
 EnumerateConversation(item, conv); 
 } 
 } 
 } 
 } 
} 


void EnumerateConversation(object item, 
 Outlook.Conversation conversation) 
{ 
 Outlook.SimpleItems items = 
 conversation.GetChildren(item); 
 if (items.Count > 0) 
 { 
 foreach (object myItem in items) 
 { 
 // In this example, enumerate only MailItem type. 
 // Other types such as PostItem or MeetingItem 
 // can appear in the conversation. 
 if (myItem is Outlook.MailItem) 
 { 
 Outlook.MailItem mailItem = 
 myItem as Outlook.MailItem; 
 Outlook.Folder inFolder = 
 mailItem.Parent as Outlook.Folder; 
 string msg = mailItem.Subject 
 + " in folder " + inFolder.Name; 
 Debug.WriteLine(msg); 
 } 
 // Continue recursion. 
 EnumerateConversation(myItem, conversation); 
 } 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Almost 4 years later, but this was incredibly helpful. The only hiccup I found was that GetConversation will not return Null, NaN, None, or any other null-like value for 'conversations' that have only 1 message, but that's easily overcome